# проблема в реализации проверки логина на занятость

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

Проблема заключаться в том что после выполнения проверки выдается что логин занят ,но когда начинаешь удалять символы из поля то сообщение "логин занят" не исчезает как это реализовать ?

Comment: навешайте на поле ввода onkeydown а далее при отслеживании удаляйте "логин занят"

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял, то как-то так:

```js
aForm = $('form');
$('#text').val('qwerty');
aForm.on('input', function (e) {
   var target = $(e.target);
   target.next().text('');
   target.removeClass('error');
});
```

```css
#text {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline: none;
  padding: 2px 5px;
}
#text.error {
  border-color: red;
}
#errorField {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <input id="text" class="error" type="text" autofocus>
  <div id="errorField">Исправьте код</div>
</form>
```